# At/from the outset

Tags: prepositions, present-perfect

Consider the sentence:

> We've been friends **at/from** the outset.

Which preposition is used?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to say. Are you still friends?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes.

Comment: Then use *from*. Otherwise you're implying you've been friends at the beginning, but stopped being friends at some later time.

Comment: @michael.hor257k since the action shows no present relevance, shouldn't I change the tense? Say, *We were friends at the outset*?

Comment: And now I don't know what you want to say again.

Comment: @michael.hor257k does *We've been friends at the outset* sound correct? (Supposing that we are no longer friends.) I think it doesn't make sense and if I wanted to use *at*, I should use a past tense.

Comment: "We've been friends *from* the outset" is fine in both grammar and logic.

"We've been friends *at* the outset" is nonsense in grammar and problematic in logic.

It could be that that you wanted to say "We *were* friends *at* the outset" and is that so? Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-the-outset-from-the-outset#:%7E:text=If%20something%20happens%20at%20the,beginning%20and%20continues%20to%20happen.) does make a distinction between the two prepositions, and your intuition is right:

> If something happens ***at** the outset* of an event, process, or period of time, it happens ***at*** the beginning of it. If something happens ***from** the outset* it happens ***from*** the beginning ***and continues to happen***.
>
> - Decide at the outset what kind of learning programme you want to follow.
> - *From the outset* he ***had put*** his trust in me, the son of his old friend.

Note the perfect tense with *from the outset*. Here is an example with ***at the outset*** from [Dict.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/at-the-outset) which is closer to your sentence:

> - ***At*** *the outset* the problem ***seemed*** simple, but then it became quite complicated.

With past events, ***at*** refers to a completed, finished state or action, so it makes no sense to prolong it to the present by using present perfect. ***From** the outset* fits well in your sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Use **since**. We use the present perfect progressive tense (e.g. 'have been') to describe an action that began in the past, continues in the present, and may continue into the future. We use 'since' to discuss the duration of something that has continued from a definite past time and until now. I have been a socialist since I was a teenager. He has been sick since last Tuesday.

[Verb tenses](https://leo.stcloudstate.edu/grammar/tenses.html)

[Since](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/since)

Comment: I thought my answer was sufficiently clear for this site. I'll vote to move it to ELL.

Comment: It seems that the OP wants to know whether to use at or from before 'the outset'. Not sure if he is referring to the tense part.

Answer (score -2):

**We've been friends at/from the outset.**

Interesting:  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/outset) 2 idioms (Farlex Partner Idioms Dictionary)

**at the outset**, also, **from the outset**.

> at/from the beginning of something; at/from the start

The reference states that the noun **outset** is rarely heard
today except in these [2] phrases.

As in:

> He wanted to explain his position from the outset.

and

> At the outset the problem seemed simple, but then it became quite
>   complicated.

It appears you can use either.